# parallax scrolling columns with different easing

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, parallax, translate

the scenario:
3 columns, middle one has different easing.
translate on mousewheel - smooth (looking like inertia on ios).

i found this example here:
    http://www.benoitchalland.com/projects

but don't know how to build it myself from scratch.

any ideas?

note: to see the effect, scroll until you see the 3 columns with images.

I tried the

```
 $window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){
 // event.preventDefault();
 var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
     $(".center").css({
         "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(0,-" + scrollTop  + "px,0)",
         "-moz-transform": "translate3d(0,-" + scrollTop  + "px,0)"
     });
});


.center {
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 800ms linear;
    transition: all 800ms linear;
}
```

but if I don't `prevendDefault()` it first jumps and then animates and if I do prevent default, it's stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time, playing around with different approaches. I didn't want this complicated parallax thing. This solution will not work in IE9 and was not tested between browsers (works in chrome).

Based on CSS3 transition-duration: 0.5s; transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; - means whenever we ask browser to change something on element, browser will perform all animations. So we can easily give new relative position by jQuery, and browser will do the trick. Place your JS after CSS or problems in Chrome. Tweak here and there.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tall">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column" data-speed="slow"></div>
    <div class="column" data-speed="fast"></div>
    <div class="column" data-speed="slow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: fixed;
}
.column {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

***JS***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Setup some vars on start
  // you can define more speeds here
  var speeds = {
    'slow': 0.5,
    'fast': 1
  };
  var noColumns = $('.column').length;
  // this contains column properties to be used later
  var columns = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < noColumns; i++) {
    columns.push({
      columnHeight: parseInt($('.column').eq(i).css('height')),
      position: 0,
      speed: speeds[$('.column').eq(i).attr('data-speed')]
    });
  }
  var previousScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var conHeight = parseInt($('.column').eq(0).css('height')) * 2;
  // We need to extend main div, to have scrolling bar active for all elements in column
  $('.tall').css('height', conHeight + 'px');
  $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
    // Do the magic
    var shift = $(this).scrollTop() - previousScroll;
    previousScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    for (var i = 0; i < noColumns; i++) {
      columns[i].position -= shift * columns[i].speed;
      $('.column').eq(i).css('top', columns[i].position + 'px');
    }
  });
});
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/dony190h/1/

Comment: Or just came to me, you could use different CSS transition times and effects for different columns - effects could be interesting